# Node.JS aws-sdk getting "socket hang up" error

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to get the pricing information of AmazonEC2 machines using "@aws-sdk/client-pricing-node" package.

Each time I will send a request to get the pricing information, process it, and send the request again, until all the information is obtained (no NextToken anymore). The following is my code.

```
const {
  PricingClient,
} = require('@aws-sdk/client-pricing-node/PricingClient');

const {
  GetProductsCommand,
} = require('@aws-sdk/client-pricing-node/commands/GetProductsCommand');

const agent = new https.Agent({
  maxSockets: 30,
  keepAlive: true,
});

const pricing = new PricingClient({
  region: "us-east-1",
  httpOptions: {
    timeout: 45000,
    connectTimeout: 45000,
    agent,
  },
  maxRetries: 10,
  retryDelayOptions: {
    base: 500,
  },
});

const getProductsCommand = new GetProductsCommand( {  ServiceCode: 'AmazonEC2', });

async function sendRequest() {
  let result = false;
  while (!result) {
    try {
      const data = await pricing.send(getProductsCommand);
      result = await handleReqResults(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}

async function handleReqResults(data) {

    // some data handling code here
    // ...

  //return false when there is "NextToken" in the response data 
  if (data.NextToken) {
    setNextToken(data.NextToken);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The code will run for a while (variable time) and then stop with the following error:

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:332:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:435:23)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  '$metadata': { retries: 0, totalRetryDelay: 0 } }
```

I had tried to run it on a GCP VM instance, and there was no such a problem. But the problem happens when I run it on my local machine.

Do anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

(BTW: my node version is v10.20.1)

Comment: As I further checked the information of "@aws-sdk/client-pricing-node", its version is 0.1.0-preview.2 released 7 months ago, and has not been updated ever since. The weekly downloads are only 80. I suspect that there are problems with this package.

I changed the code to use the "aws-sdk" directly and everything is working well.